# Graficos em pdf no R

Tags: r, pdf

Eu tenho o seguinte exercício e estou com duvida no item b em negrito.

Faça uma análise de dados, usando lm(), entre duas variáveis, tal como fizemos em sala, porém deve-se importar dados de alguma fonte qualquer, usando read.table() ou comandos equivalentes de acordo com o formato dos dados.

(1) Dados -- escolha as variáveis que quer trabalhar e manipule os dados numa planilha eletrônica; exporte o arquivo no formato desejado para ser importado no R.

(2) Ajuste -- depois de importar os dados, faça um ajuste com lm() usando diferentes modelos (formas funcionais) e coloque no gráfico os pontos dos dados e os ajustes encontrados (formato PDF).

(3) enviar em arquivo compactado contendo apenas 2 arquivos:

a. o arquivo de dados;

**b. o código a ser executado em R -- é importante ressaltar que o usuário deve executar o código com source() e o código deve fazer toda a tarefa: importação, análise e geração dos plots em PDF, e uso do comando summary para apresentar as informações estatísticas importantes de cada modelo.**

Como gerar o gráfico em pdf?

Answer (score 2):

Use a função [`pdf`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/pdf.html)

Exemplo:

```
pdf('grafico.pdf')
H <- c(2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5,6)
counts <- table(H)
barplot(counts)
dev.off()
```